# What default encoding is used when using StreamWriter to write into a file with no Encoding parameter?

Tags: vb.net, encoding, streamwriter

I had a situation where we produce a file for our client, and the file would contain some special characters like accented i or a (`í`, `á`) etc.

Originally, we used this code to open file for output:

`Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fullpath, True)`

However, the `í` and `á` would show up in the file as 2 character combinations of bytes with hex codes `c3 ad` for the `í` and `c3 a1` for the `á`

We fixed the issue by enforcing the Windows1252 encoding when writing to the file (which is same as `Encoding.Default`, but according to [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnste/archive/2005/03/15/don-t-use-encoding-default.aspx) we should NOT be using `Encoding.Default`):

`Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fullpath, True, Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252))`

**Question:** if `Encoding.Default` is not really a default encoding when no Encoding parameter was supplied, which encoding is the default default (pardon the pun) encoding?

**Question2:** probably the same answer as QUestion 1, what is the default default encoding for `StreamReader` if you don't specify `Encoding` parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you didn't really fix the issue.  To get "c3 ad for the í" you must use Encoding.Utf8

Which is what StreamWriter is already using.  However, it uses the Utf8Encoding constructor that takes the *encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier* argument and passes *false*.  Otherwise known as the BOM (Byte Order Mark).  The BOM tells the program that reads the file unequivocally what Unicode encoding is used.  Sadly, Microsoft cannot force a BOM because the Unicode consortium, in a highly uncharacteristic moment of temporary insanity, made a BOM optional.

It probably works now because the program falls back to the system's default encoding when it can't find the BOM.  You might have guessed correctly at 1252, it is common, but certainly no guarantee.  Fix:

```
  Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fullpath, True, Encoding.Utf8)
```

Do beware the *True* argument you use.  Which *appends* text to the file.  If the file already contains text then you can't get the BOM added anymore.  Also a rather nasty problem if the file got started with a different encoding, you certainly don't want to get a mix.  Do everything you can to avoid having to use *True*.

Comment: Appending to the file is a no-issue in my case, but your point is very valid and important. You are correct about BOM, I manually add the 3 BOM bytes to the beginning of the file and a suddenly the  issue is fixed. However, I am puzzled why you think forcing to write in Windows1252 encoding is not a fix? Client has no issues with the fix and is able to read the file with all the special characters.